# How to disable backup when a mysql db is first restored form a snapshot?

Tags: boto3, amazon-rds

Here is my code that creates a new db by restoring from a snapshot

```
rds = boto3.client("rds")
snapshots_result = rds.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot(
    DBInstanceIdentifier=target_db_name,
    DBSnapshotIdentifier=snapshot_id,
    DBSubnetGroupName="mysql"
    )
```

The problem is AWS rds, once the db is restored, will start a backup process.

However in my use case, my intention is to restore a main db to a 'read-only' db: i.e. for a bunch of non-critical user to access slight stale data in order to lower the load on the main db.

I don't need to backup the data in the new, 'read-only' db.

I have checked the documentation but I cannot find any way to disable bak from the `restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot` API.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make another call to modify the new instance and set BackupRetentionPeriod to 0